How can I make my electric motor 230 V 18.5 kW to run on the primary source of 380 V?
How can I make my electric motor 230 V 18.5 kW to run on the primary source of 380 V?


Probably by getting a big transformer to step down the voltage.  But it may be easier just to get a motor rated for the right voltage.


220V delta converts to 380V wye (when reconfigured) , but the boiler plate doesn't tell me to which winding configuration the 220V applies.
However a search on YE3-180M-4 strongly suggest that this is a 380V motor (presumably when configured wye)
